# Cannot GET /about page in MEAN application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes, mean-stack

I want to integrate angular routing into my node app, but I'm getting an error and not sure how to resolve it. I just want to have a link to redirects to an about.html file, that is inside a directory called public.

In my index.html file I have a link:

```
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

In my server.js I have this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('contactlist', ['contactlist']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

In my js file I have the $routeProvider set up as follows:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
   .when('/about',{
      templateUrl: '/about.html'
  });
});
```

Comment: I assume you have typed address like localhost:port/about into address bar in your browser an hit enter. In that case you need something like app.get('*',function(req,res){res.render('index');}); to serve the index page where you setup you angular app which then route you to about page on client. Just find some tutorials. There's a bit more code needed then what you currently have.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me what you mean exactly or do you know of any tutorials that explain this step by step?

Comment: Thinking about it now you don't even need app.get if you have index.html file in public folder. Anyways there are thousands of tutorials just google it. Search for "express angular routing"

Comment: Angular js appends a hash(#) to you app URL by default ..
so any url which you want to access which is configured in your routeProvider ...try using # before them....in your case it will be ...href='#/about'.....